# Why won't my the png associated with the my ERC721 token appear on https://sepolia.etherscan.io/

Tags: sepolia

I am successfully minting tokens in that they appear on https://sepolia.etherscan.io/. However, the information that I provide for the TokenURI is not appearing.

Here is the link to the IFPS JSON that I use as the TokenURI:

https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmbT3Q1dRFGqemJ4d3DKJuZZtEMTAzVdXsSbtGYYGMR92c

Here is the actually JSON

```
{
  "name": "DiLTy",
  "description": "The Blockchain Journal NFT",
  "image": "ipfs://QmdrSbo7sCLKXE8Ai8eSFhhfzhLpbh79PCWyndRNs2C93p"
}
```

When I call the URL ipfs://QmdrSbo7sCLKXE8Ai8eSFhhfzhLpbh79PCWyndRNs2C93p in my Brave browser, the graphic does appear.

But, when I view the token at https://sepolia.etherscan.io/token/0xf9eda64619ce386868f8b54f9b0e976f3166ed30 as you can see, there is no image associated with it. Also, as you can see, an hour has passed since I first minted tokens using the TokenURI. So, I think indexing might have completed. Still, no png image.

[image: Token history]

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide. I am totally mystified as to what is going on. Please forgive me if the cause of the problem is due to an error on my part.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the the issue about Sepolia. The NFT `png` appears fine on https://testnets.opensea.io/